# How to Move cursor from one EditText to another one and back to the first edit text if a custom button is clicked?

Tags: android, text, edit

i am basically developing a small mathematics app, in a activity their will be  problems like additions subtractions etc. the user has to fill the answers in edittext from the custom buttons from 0-9, a dot, a slash button and a backspace button which i created on the same activity. now i like to add up and down button, so that when the up button is pressed the cursor has to move towards upside edit text and vice versa.

here is a sample code which i used

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@android:id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some string of text"
        />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@android:id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some string of text"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
    public class Example extends Activity {
        TextView et1;
        TextView et2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.et2);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Selection.setSelection((Editable) et2.getText(), et1.getSelectionStart());
                et2.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of of your EditTexts and a variable containing your current position, defaulted to 0, meaning the first text box. Then if the user presses the up button, if the variable is greater than 0, set the position -1 and then get the textbox object from the array and call focus(). Below is an example piece of code, its not accurate but should get you started

```
List<EditText> textfields = null;
int currentTextFieldPosition = 0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textfields = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    textfield1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
    .....

    textfields.add(textfield1);
    ......
}

protected OnClickListener mBtnUpClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public boolean onClick()
    {
        if (currentTextfieldPosition > 0)
        {
            currentTextfieldPosition--;
            textfields.get(currentTextFieldPosition).focus()
        }
    }
}
```